# Time Zone issue with server and html client

Tags: java, javascript, html, timezone, client-server

Basic requirement is Server has data with GMT +00.00 and Browser needs to request data from server between certain dates(not time).
Let's say, one record saved on server on 28th March,2015 Night from USA local time. Server is following GMT +00.00 so record saved with 29th March, 2015 morning with GMT.

Now HTML is retrieving same record from the server. Server have GMT 29th March,2015. But now I want to display local date as per time zone of any browser. Client and server is communication with date only not time.

Right now server will give 29th March, 2015 to client. But It should display as a local date i.e. 28th March, 2015. So how can I manage display date among the different time zone?

Any idea or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: which database you are using ?

Comment: You're not transfering enough information to accomplish your goal. Either the server will need to send at least the GMT hour in addition to the date, or the client must tell the server what timezone it's in so the server can do the maths itself. Regardless, there is no pure client-side solution.

Comment: @Touffy: Basically client is a reporting portal and Portal is requesting date range for the data which needs to be show on Graph and tables. So they do not have any hours in the portal. It is pure based on Date only.

Comment: I understand that you don't want to display the hours in the end, but you need hours to adjust the dates before you show them in your tables. Can you do either of the things I suggested in my previous comment? the solution will depend on that.

Comment: @Touffy: Got your point. Thanks for your suggestion.. :)

Answer (score -1):

Well, one solution would be to create a column in your Database with the real timestamp of the date, time included. So, you could show this date (reformated if you want) to client and keep the GMT +00.00 for the process part.

The problem here, if think is that since you don't save the time part, it's impossible to say if it was Day/Night.

The other solution would be to change your actual date to datetime and save it in GMT +00.00 with another column specifying the offset between GMT +00.00 region and the other (here, USA).

Some maths should do.

I can't propose a written solution since you don't specify your server language (unless it's Javascript ?).

By all means, good luck with that ;).